# How to make a Relative Layout Duplicate Itself Inside a Linear Layout On Button Click

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an alert dialogue set up inside a RelativeLayout. A small section is a ListView with a RelativeLayout inside. My xml file is as follows:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="10dp">

 ...

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@id/bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/dialoguelistview"
    android:padding="10dp">
<RelativeLayout>    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"          
        android:hint="@string/Item" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="@string/Quantity" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Item"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Quantity"
        android:hint="@string/Cost" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Item"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="30dip" 
        android:layout_height="30dip" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Item"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="@string/another_item"
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:onClick = "addAnotherItem"></Button>

 </RelativeLayout>
 </ListView>

...

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When the button is clicked, I need the inner relative layout to duplicate itself inside the list view. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: put it in another layout file and use an inflater.

Comment: @njzk2 How do I put an inflator in this xml file?

Comment: you don't. you inflate from your java code, apparently from a click listener

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate layout xml file for **RealtiveLayout** that you want to inflate.

**Example**

**The xml of the parent page is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="em.example.InfoActivity">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/infolayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Child Page**

```
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#55934d"
android:padding="5dp"> 

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextAddress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT ADDRESS:"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is your activity.java code**

```
public void addChildLayout(){
    //Inflater service
    LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //parent layout xml refrence
    LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
    //Child layout xml refrence
    View view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.infoitem, null);
    //add child to parent
    linearLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

Using the above pattern you can dynamically add new views.

Comment: If you think that it solves your problem, mark it as an answer.

Comment: I tried this and it said that add(view) is underfined for LinearLayout. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @JunebugsinJuly It's a typo mistake ..It should be addView(view)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to keep two copies of the relativelayout in the parent linearlayout . Keep the visibility of one of them as 'gone' and mark it visible when you want it to appear.

Benefit of this approach would be to minimize code.