# layout.requestfocus() in android (dynamic content)

Tags: android, layout

I have made an application in which I will be dynamically adding image and text to the application for this i am using

> 1.relative layout (main layout)
>
> 1.(a) linear layout   ( a linear layout containing all the 1.(b) values)
>
> 1.(b) linear layout    ( d layout  which contains a image and a text) , each (1.(b)) layout contain one image and one text

now as I am running this app on set top box (with remote) with android, which is connected to smart tv,,,,, so i have to control my app with a remote control provided with the set top box.

so what I want is when the application loads , the focus will be on the first ((1.(b) linear layout)) i.e. on the first pair of image and text.

already done:- I have used `requestFocus()` but of no  use

any help will be greatly appreciated thanks in advance cheers !!!!!!!

```
   the code snippet is as follows:-
           activity
                         LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain1);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                75, 98);
         params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
         params.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 0);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramrelative = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                170, 158);
         paramrelative.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 0); 
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(180,
                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         p.setMargins(2,0, 0, 0);
         
        //Create four 
       for(int j= 0;j<=count-1;j++) 
        {   
            // Create LinearLayout
           ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
            final RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
     
            ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_bg);
           

            
           
            
            
            
            ll.setLayoutParams(paramrelative);
            ll.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            ll.setClickable(true);

            
           
            
            
            

           
             
        //    final String url= separated[j+1];
          
             
            // Create Button
            final  Button img = new Button(this);
            final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
          
                // Give button an ID
               img.setId(j+1);
               
               int s=img.getId();
               
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, s);

            tv.setLayoutParams(p);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
              //File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                  // File sdcardPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    //      .getPath() + "/CATEGORIES");
               String filename=finalname[j];
               File myDir = new File(sdcardPath,filename);
            //     File myDir = new File(sdcardPath, "CATEGORIES_hotelinfo.png");
               String m1 = myDir.getPath();
               Resources res = getResources();
             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m1);
               BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
              
           
              img.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(m1.toString()));

        //2ndaugust2014      tv.setText(finalname[j]);
            int s1= finalname[j].indexOf(".");
            final String finalname1=finalname[j].substring(0,s1);
            tv.setText(finalname1);
      
            
               
              img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                        String newPath=newPath1+finalname1;
                      
                      File sdcardPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getPath() +newPath); 
                      new CountDownTimer(2000,1000) {

                             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                   ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_btn_d);      //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                             }

                             public void onFinish() {
                                 ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_bg); 
                                

                             

                             }
                          }.start();
                      // if the directory does not exist, create it
                      if (!sdcardPath.exists())
                      {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "redirecting to www."+finalname1+".com", 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                      
                      else  
                      
              

                      {  Intent intent = new Intent(Second60grid.this,Second60grid.class);
                  //  startActivity(intent);
                    //  i.setClassName(packageName, activitylast);
                    
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                   "name" + finalname1, 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 
                      
                      
                      
                      
           intent.putExtra("nameoffile",newPath+"/");
              startActivity(intent);
                       
                  }
                  }
              });
             
                // set the layoutParams on the button
               img.setLayoutParams(params);
               //Add button to LinearLayout
           //    setContentView(sv);
                ll.addView(img);
                ll.addView(tv);
                
            if(j==0)
                {
                  ll.requestFocus();
                }

               //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
                lm.addView(ll);  
              
              

        }
```

and the xml file is as follows:-----

```
                             <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"> 
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="200dip"
android:id="@+id/rl1"
 > 
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="CATEGORIES" />
 <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearMain1"
      android:layout_below="@+id/TEXT0"
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:background="#80000000">
           </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearMain2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/linearMain1"
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:background="#80000000">
                       </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_below="@+id/linearMain2"
                   android:orientation="horizontal" 
                  android:id="@+id/linearMain3"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:background="#80000000"
                         >
                     </LinearLayout>  
                      <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_below="@+id/linearMain3"
                       android:orientation="horizontal" 
                 android:id="@+id/linearMain4"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="#80000000"
               >  </LinearLayout> 
                  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearMain4"
                   android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:id="@+id/linearMain5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="#80000000"
                 >
            </LinearLayout>
             </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="1400dp"
             android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="#80ffffff" 
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
               android:id="@+id/rl2"
            >
         <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/remote_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:src="@drawable/remote_btn" 
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/remote_btn2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/remote_btn"
        android:text="MOVE" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/remote_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TEXT1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/remote_btn2" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TEXT1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/remote_btn2"
       android:text="SELECT" />
      </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rl3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="800dip"
      android:background="#10ffffff" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
      android:layout_marginBottom = "10dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/rl2"
         >
       <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttoniptv"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
      android:text="iptv" 
       android:background="#FF0000"/>
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttontvchannels"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   
      android:layout_below="@+id/buttoniptv"
      android:background="#FF0000"
      android:text="tvchannels" />
       <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttoninternet"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 
      android:layout_below="@+id/buttontvchannels"
      android:background="#FF0000"
      android:text="internet" />
   </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are currently adding view in ascending order
    parentView.addView(child, 0);
Add it in Descending Order:
    parentView.addView(child, parentView.getChildCount() - 1);

Comment: @dpsingh :didnt get you brother !!!!!!

Comment: You are inflating linear layout containing ImageView and TextView into RelativeLayout and at some point you are adding it to RelativeLayout.addView(LinearLayout).

Comment: So it goes in ascending order  and you have do it in Descending order so that the request focus goes to the top LinearLayout

Comment: will give it a try and will let u know cheers

Comment: I have posted it as an answer mark it as true if you find it correct.

Comment: i have tried it @dpsingh still it didnt worked :(

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: @dpsingh check i have edited the question !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently adding view in ascending order

```
parentView.addView(child, 0);
```

Add it in Descending Order:

```
parentView.addView(child, parentView.getChildCount() - 1);
```

Comment: Use the below given approach to inflate view at runtime
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145842/how-to-make-a-relative-layout-duplicate-itself-inside-a-linear-layout-on-button/25146120#25146120

Comment: lemme give it a try dude @dpsingh